# Adjusting icons of accordion

Tags: css, icons, accordion

I have the following accordion setup: https://jsfiddle.net/n4tmjaqd/1/

I would like to change the icons of the tabs so that they become plus and minus icon. Plus when closed, and minus when opened. How can I adjust the CSS in order to make this change? Can it even be done with CSS only or does the function have to change? Any guidance is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }

});
```

CSS:

```
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-title">
              TITLE 1
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              CONTENT 1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-title">
              TITLE 2
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              CONTENT 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-title">
              TITLE 3
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              CONTENT 3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where to adjust so that I can add the icons?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Made smooth transition when click on the button.
> 2. You don't have to use multiple `div` for this, you can still make it simple I have just retained your HTML code, you can think for making it optimized in future.

here is how it looks:

[image]

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-title");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-title {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion-title:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion-title:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: red;
  /* change the color you want here */
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.accordion-content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <button class="accordion-title">TITLE 1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <button class="accordion-title">TITLE 2</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <button class="accordion-title">TITLE 3</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works however now the accordion no longer closes when another one is opened. Any way to adjust that?

Comment: I've got it to work. Would you know how I can change the colour of the icon?

Comment: Great! I have updated my code for `color` I have marked as red, feel free to change the color.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm trying to use unicodes 2795 and 2796. These do not change colour. Is this intentional?

Comment: Nope, that should work too! here is the fiddle of 2795 and 2796: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/mfub914h/1/

Comment: no it didn’t unfortunately. Both on mobile and on desktop it does not work for me. Also can’t see it on the fiddle

Comment: why not on fiddle, what is the expectation here!? I can see the red + and - symbol in fiddle even in the answer I have posted, what is it I am missing?

Comment: Could it be a browser issue?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Both safari and chrome

Comment: I am using chrome and it works fine, I tried in firefox too it works there also. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @Manjuboys are you sure you are using 2795 and 2796? Because 002B and 2212 change colour for me but not 2795 and 2796

Comment: @fiddle thanks for letting me know! it shows gray now but as attached screenshot before i changed it to 2795 on that day, may be it is browser caching I assume. Anyway you got it worked with color now? if so I am glad the answer helped you if not let me know what color you need.